# Facebook actual share VS Facebook Object Debugger /linter

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

When I debug my page with [facebook debug tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) all my *og properties* appear as I expect. Although, when I share the exact same link on `facebook` the `og:image` is ignored. Here is the page with this problem on my [site](http://slashmagazine.ca/post/63/catching-up-with-silvia-mittermuller/en_US.html)

What am I doing wrong? What can I do to improve my code?

Comment: I would remove the ASCII art from the top of the HTML source (or at least move it below the meta tags).

Comment: ascii art was added after I've noticed the problem. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest adding open graph  tags as outlined here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Comment: Thanks that helped. I have consulted that page at the moment of creating the site. The thing I didn't noticed that was causing the problem in my case is the following point:  "The image must be at least 50px by 50px and have a maximum aspect ratio of 3:1." mine had a larger ratio. thanks for making me reread.